# WWW is getting 404 but without it works fine for most of the virtual host domains, upstream redirecting but how to change upstream?

Tags: apache2, proxy, upstream

Aloha,
I have:
Ubuntu 20.04 running on a Akamai(was Linode) shared processors with the latest Apache2 server and 8 or so different domains, for the majority they work correctly. But the main one and one other entering www in front of example.com gets me 404. I been researching it a while and the since it works fine for some and all the domains have the exact same configuration files, except for it appropriate name in it's correct location. (only exception is I use the same webmaster email for all of them)

Anyway I found other trouble shooting sites saying arbitrary upstream redirection from internet servers caching (most of the posts were 10 or more years old,) ISA will redirect, but that is a Microsoft server and I can't find anyway of anything out of the ordinary with @dig@ They said they fixed upstream routing, but didn't give any details (they didn't have a proxy server protecting an internet app or such) so what is Apache for stripping any redirections for such arbitrary domain redirection?

`ServerAlias` already in every vhost.conf file.

Comment: I already said all the config files are exactly the same. AND already researched the issue since most of the virtual hosts work. I want to know how to get upstream server to dump their cache or force a rewrite of incoming headers. Most rewrite references are about changing internal routing. should have an If conditional statement I'm quite sure since need to check and reparse the header. Maybe a good idea anyway since I'm getting tons, 10 pages, of access logs for 3 seconds of logging and haven't published it yet. But that is another topic.

Comment: No guessing just read what is in front of you. This request is not for new information on existing config files. If you don't know how to get upstream servers to dump cache or how to write `If While` conditions to rewrite incoming headers then try not put others down or go thumping documentation as canonical and infallible. (It isn't personal)